# 'Changes from' or 'Changes to'

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

We are going to be closing early (or all day) during the holidays.
Would it be more appropriate to say:

> These are the changes from our usual schedule:
>       Monday Close at 5, Tuesday Closed, Wed...etc

or

> These are the changes to our usual schedule:
>       Monday Close at 5, Tuesday Closed, Wed...etc

More importantly, why is one more correct than the other (assuming they're not both okay!)?

Comment: "Changes to" is a better choice because you are listing the new hours. "Changes from" would be more appropriate if you listed the old hours.

Comment: In either case it would be better to display the old hours and indicate the special not-permanent holiday hours as changes. One sentence does not do the same job as a calendar listing with changes in red.

Answer (score 3):

"From" is correct and unambiguous. "To" is also correct, but ambiguous.

"From" is used here to show where or when something started. "Changes from your usual schedule" implies that the usual schedule was the original schedule and that the current schedule is not the usual schedule.

"To" can be used here either to show that the schedule is receiving the action of the change or to show direction. In the first sense, "changes to your usual schedule" means that the usual schedule received the change, and that the current schedule is not the usual schedule. In the second sense, "changes to your usual schedule" means that what existed before was not the usual schedule, and that that was changed and the change resulted in your usual schedule. You see, "to" is ambiguous.

Use "from" or use neither. Don't use "to."